# Many-to-many relationship select and order by

Tags: php, mysql, many-to-many

I have a many-to-many relationship between two tables: person and favorites.  I have three columns:

```
person_id         int(8)
favorites_id      int(8)
is_main_favorite  enum('y','n')
```

as:

```
person_id | favorite_id | is_main_favorite

2         | 1           |   'y'
2         | 2           |   'n'
3         | 1           |   'n'
3         | 2           |   'n'
1         | 1           |   'y'
1         | 2           |   'y'
```

I'm using PHP and MySQL.

How I can retrieve `person_id` that have (`favorite_id` 1 and 2 together) and order the result by `person id` that have more `is_main_favorite ='y'`, so the result should be as:

```
person_id 

1          (because he has favorite_id 1 and 2 and have two is_main_favorite = 'y')
2          (because he has favorite_id 1 and 2 and have one is_main_favorite = 'y')
```

Comment: Why isn't `person_id` of 3 listed (last, because there are zero 'y' values)?

Answer (score 1):

Probably something similar to this:

```
SELECT
    a.person_id
FROM
    table AS a,
    table AS b
WHERE
    a.person_id = b.person_id AND
    a.favorite_id = 1 AND
    b.favorite_id = 2
ORDER BY
    ( IF( a.is_main_favorite = "y", 1, 0 )
      +
      IF( b.is_main_favorite = "y", 1, 0 ) ) DESC
```

By the way: You may want to store 1/0 instead of y/n in the database so that you won't need the IF call

Comment: This will sort incorrectly if `b.is_main_favorite` is `y` and `a.is_main_favorite` is `n`.

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

```
SELECT `person_id`
FROM `persons`
LEFT JOIN `favorites` AS `one`
 ON `favorites`.`person_id` = `persons`.`person_id`
LEFT JOIN `favorites` AS `two`
 ON `favorites`.`person_id` = `persons`.`person_id`
WHERE `one`.`favorite_id` = ?
AND `two`.`favorite_id` = ?
ORDER BY (
 IF(`one`.`is_main_favorite` = "y", 1, 0)
 +
 IF(`two`.`is_main_favorite` = "y", 1, 0)
) DESC
```

### How it works

First, the `favorites` table is joined to the `persons` table twice, each as it's own table (`one` and `two`). Then, both `favorite_id`s are checked to see if they exist. If they are both present, the row is included in the result set, and sorted by the count of `is_main_favorite` (2 if two "y", 1 if one "y", or 0).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT p.person_id
FROM person AS p, favorites AS f1, favorites AS f2
WHERE p.person_id = f1.person_id AND
      p.person_id = f2.person_id AND
      f1.favorite_id IS NOT NULL AND
      f2.favorite_id IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY
( IF( f1.is_main_favorite = "y", 1, 0 )
  +
  IF( f2.is_main_favorite = "y", 1, 0 ) ) DESC
```

Comment: This will sort incorrectly if `f2.is_main_favorite` is `y` and `f1.is_main_favorite` is `n`.